# Check if last element of all arrays are empty

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I need to check if all elements of an array have an empty string as **last* element. If this is the case, they should be removed.

So this...

```
var data = [
    [ 'field 1', 'field 2', '' ],
    [ 'field 1', 'field 2', '' ],
    [ 'field 1', 'field 2', '' ]
];
```

should become:

```
var dataNew = [
    [ 'field 1', 'field 2' ],
    [ 'field 1', 'field 2' ],
    [ 'field 1', 'field 2' ]
];
```

This array:

```
var data = [
    [ 'field 1', 'field 2', '' ],
    [ 'field 1', 'field 2', 'field 3' ],
    [ 'field 1', 'field 2', '' ]
];
```

shouldn't be changed - as the last element of the second array is not an empty string.

Comment: Where is the code that shows how you have already attempted to solve this? Or were you expecting someone to do all of this for you?  If so, this isn't a code writing service

Comment: Please provide your solutions and the use case description.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple solution using `while` loop, `Array.map` and `Array.slice` functions:

```
function checkLastItemEmpty(data) {
    var unchanged = false, len = data.length, last, new_arr;

    while (len--) {
        last = data[len][data[len].length - 1];
        if (last) {
            unchanged = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    // if the initial array should be changed with deleting the last value of each item
    if (!unchanged) {
        data = data.map(function (v) {
            return v.slice(0, -1);
        });
    }
    return data;
}

var data = checkLastItemEmpty(data);
```

---

As for your additional requirement: "*if I want to remove all empty elements at the end? Example: `[ 'one', '', '', '' ]` should become `[ 'one' ]` (if all others arrays have same empty elements)*") - here is an ***additional approach*** using `Array.some` function:

```
function checkLastItemEmpty(data) {
    var unchanged = false, len = data.length, last_items, new_arr;

    while (len--) {
        last_items = data[len].slice(1).some(function(v){  return Boolean(v); });
        if (last_items) {
            unchanged = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (!unchanged) {
        data = data.map(function (v) {
            return v.slice(0,1);
        });
    }
    return data;
}
```

Comment: What do I have to change, if I want to remove all empty elements at the end? Example: `[ 'one', '', '', '' ]` should become `[ 'one' ]` (if all others arrays have same empty elements)

Answer (score 0):

The idea is to put the last elements in an array and check wether all the items of the array are empty or not with

```
var all_empty = checkArray.every(function(v) { return v.length == 0; });
```

If `checkArray` has a single value that's not empty then do nothing with your array otherwise remove all the last items of your initial array :

```
for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
    if(all_empty){
      data[i].splice(-1)
    }
}
```

For example :

```
var data = [
    [ 'field 1', 'field 2', '' ],
    [ 'field 1', 'field 2', '' ],
    [ 'field 1', 'field 2', '' ]
];
```

`checkArray` will be `['','','']`
    and 
    `all_empty` will be `true`
    so you can remove with `data.splice`

but if

```
var data = [
    [ 'field 1', 'field 2', '' ],
    [ 'field 1', 'field 2', 'field 3' ],
    [ 'field 1', 'field 2', '' ]
];
```

`checkArray` will be `['','field 3','']`

https://jsfiddle.net/2r6s9ad1/3/

Answer (score 0):

```js
var data = [
  ['field 1', 'field 2', ''],
  ['field 1', 'field 2', ''],
  ['field 1', 'field 2', '']
];

var data2 = [
  ['field 1', 'field 2', ''],
  ['field 1', 'field 2', 'field 3'],
  ['field 1', 'field 2', '']
];


function removeEmpty(data) {
  var isEmpty = 0;

  data.forEach(function(arr) {
    if (arr[arr.length - 1]) {
      isEmpty++;
    }
  });

  if (!isEmpty) {
    data.forEach(function(arr) {
      return arr.pop();
    });
    return data;
  }
  return data;
}

console.log(removeEmpty(data));
console.log(removeEmpty(data2));
```

Output:

```
first array [["field 1", "field 2"], ["field 1", "field 2"], ["field 1", "field 2"]]

second array [["field 1", "field 2", ""], ["field 1", "field 2", "field 3"], ["field 1", "field 2", ""]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass over the data at least once to check if the status of any of the last elements of the nested arrays is an empty string. If even only one is you can raise a flag and just simply return the array. If the flag isn't raised and they're all empty you need to iterate over the array again to remove those elements.

```
function looper(arr, pass) {

  // copy the array on the first pass
  // so we don't break the original
  var tmp = !pass ? arr.slice(0) : arr;
  var flag = false;
  pass = pass || 0;
  var index = -1;
  var a = tmp[0].length - 1;
  while (++index < tmp.length) {

    // on the first pass if one of the last elements
    // is not an empty string set the flag to true and break
    // out of the loop
    if (!pass && tmp[index][a] !== '') {
      flag = true;
      break;
    }

    // if we're on our second pass remove the last element(s)
    if (pass) tmp[index].pop();
  }

  // if we're on the first pass and the flag
  // is not set, loop over the array again
  // and remove the last elements
  if (!pass && !flag) looper(tmp, ++pass);

  // return the completed array
  return tmp;
}

looper(data);
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/07gbdddu/3/)

Answer (score 0):

This is also a nice little function.

Just give the `function` your `array` and it will
`return` the new `array`.
**Really simple logic.**

```js
var data = [
  ['field 1', 'field 2', ''],
  ['field 1', 'field 2', ''],
  ['field 1', 'field 2', '']
];

function checkEmpty(array) {
  var tmpArr = array;
  for (var i = 0; i < tmpArr.length; i++) {
    if (tmpArr[i].indexOf("") === -1 | tmpArr[i].lastIndexOf("") !== tmpArr.length - 1) {
      return array; // if there is no "" or "" is not the last index -> stop and return old array
    } else {
      tmpArr[i].pop(); // else delete "" from array
    }
  }
  return tmpArr;
}


var newData = checkEmpty(data); // <-- newData is the result

document.write(JSON.stringify(newData)); // display result
```